# PING error code 87: what is it?

Tags: windows-ce, ping

When I ping from windows CE I got ping error:
PING: transmit failed, error code 87
But only some IPs can be successfully pinged.
What does this mean, the 87 error?

Comment: If you use Visual Studio, you can go to tools and press the "Error lookup" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

winerror.h, line 702:

```
#define ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER          87L
```